# Sort/filter in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

All new to this VBA
I've made a sheet with sales number, like:

```
Jerry 5 6 2
Lisa  2 8 3
Homer 3 6 1
```

I want to make it so when I say largest number first or smallest. All the values are "attached" to the name and move up and down as one.
Right now all the numbers move independent and isn't locked together or to the name. Any idea how a code that could do that would look like?

If I haven't been specific enough, just say the word and ill try again.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: okay. sorry to bother you then. i'm blindly guessing myself atm, dont know what to search for or anything, found some great solutions on this site and thought maybe you could help me as well. but i haven't got a code to share since i haven't wrote anything that could work towards it yet.

Comment: Well, make sure to take the [tour] and visit the [help]. We're not very good as a site to learn stuff.

Comment: Greetings, as partners said we can't give you the code unless you try a bit first

Comment: just blindly guessing, but maybe you just can't use Excel's sort properly? Simply clicking the sort button will keep the values "attached", unless you really cock something up. There is no need for VBA. Just google "Excel sorting".

Answer (score 0):

Usually the "record macro" will get you a long way.
This is the code I got when I used it:

```
Range("A1:D3").Select
Range("B1").Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B1"), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:D3")
    .Header = xlNo
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```